# Demo Store Notice not changing

Tags: phtml

I want to use the demo store notice as a ANNUAL LEAVE notice, however when I go into the notices.phtml file, and update it, the site doesn't display the new message.

I have tried refreshing cache, clearing cache and even manually deleting the cache and session files

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I followed

https://www.hostknox.com/clients/knowledgebase/57/How-to-change-the-text-of-the-Magento-Demo-Store-Notice.html

However I needed to find my own theme notices file, not the default one

Instead of

**/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/notices.phtml**

it was

**/app/design/frontend/MyThemeName/MyThemeFolder/template/page/html/notices.phtml***

Answer (score 0):

To enable/disable the Demo Store Notice you must set it in the Admin.

System -> Configuration -> Design -> HTML Head -> "Display Demo Store Notice" at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

As of Magento 2.2.x the file is located in:

**/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/notices.phtml**